# Разветвление сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, seo

Представьте ситуацию, когда при входе на сайт выдается модальное окно и спрашивает вы хотите перейти на сайт кока кола или пепси? При клике на какой либо из этих двух вариантов загружается данный контент.

Сайт один, логика идентичная, нужен способ как разделять.

1 - вариант это через cookie

2 - по url

Оба эти варианты не особо нравятся, может кто сталкивался с похожим?

Comment: Вопрос довольно общий. Можно сделать 2 разных проекта, которые будут редиректить друг на друга при выборе отличного от себя варианта в модалке. Можно сделать 1 проект с 2 разными Areas.

Comment: Ну захочу я сайт кока-колы в закладки добавить, что мне делать? При каждом заходе нажимать кнопку?

Comment: Не нужно его в закладки добавлять :) 
Сайт двух недельный ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего такое разделение производится при помощи "Области" (Areas). 
При добавленеии новой области создаётся мини-проект в котором вы можете реализовать нужный вам функционал для этой области.

В данном случае у вас есть проект "сайт.ру" и в него нужно добавить две области "кола" и "пепси".

Про маршрутизацию и области доступным языком написано [здесь.](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.1.php)

Answer (score 5):

Если хотите, чтобы ваш сайт был проиндексирован поисковиками, то разные разделы должны иметь разные URL. Ни один поисковик не прочитает ваши мысли и не будет переключать режимы в печенье с помощью кнопок на главной странице. URL должен уникально идентифицировать вашу страницу.

В идеале использование сайта должно быть возможно без печенья и без JS скриптов. Тогда проблем с индексацией не возникнет ни у одного поисковика.

Если сайты совсем отдельные, то можно выделить их на отдельные домены или субдомены.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но сайт всего на 2 недели, ему не нужны никакие индексации поисковиком.

Будет лишь одна основная страница с модальным окном и каждый раз пускай выбирают Кола или Пепси, а дальше уже сайты идентичную логику несут.

Comment: @pablo Если вам плевать на удобство пользователей и индексацию поисковиками, то делайте любым возможным способом, разницы нет.

Comment: не то что бы плевать, но вы все правильно говорите, нужно думать о пользователях, а их будет около 2т

С точки зрения реализации если делать через URL, то получается нужна страничка 1 которая с модальным окном, дальше нужны еще 2 разные странички + на IIS будет 3 сайта? это же жесть или я что то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: на IIS будет 3 сайта крутиться и все они будут идти к одной папке и на один проект.

Заголовок с модальным окном сайт.ru
потом кола.сайт.ru и пепси.сайт.ru .

Когда я захожу на сайт то у меня выбор кола или пепси и редирект делаю .

Перехожу на кола.сайт.ru и там в коде распознается url кола .

Что скажите?

Comment: @pablo Ну да, вам надо, чтобы один код обслуживал все URL. Как конкретно реализуется роутинг, не знаю.